# Поддержка JavaScript и cookies в WebBrowser

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

Пытался зайти в Вконтакте. Мне выдало

> для работы с сайтом необходима поддержка javascript и cookies.

Я так понял что это браузер основан на эксплорере, хотя в эксплорере нормально заходит.

Comment: Или может можно как-то другой браузер подключить в делфи?

Comment: Можно попробовать [Chromium](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3), хотя стандартный TWebBrowser поддерживает javascript и cookies. Может вы Cookie Manager не подключили.